# problema al integrar php en host

Tags: php, html, hosting

Espero me puedan ayudar,
 llevo un tiempo en esto

cuando ejecuto un php para "iniciar sesión" en localhost (con Xampp) funciona normalmente comprueba el usuario y contraseña en mi bd_mysql y me devuelve "TRUE" pero al subirlo a un host la función no se ejecuta.
este es mi php

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['contrasena'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];


if ($db->checkExistUser($email,$contrasena))
{
$response["exists"] = TRUE;

echo json_encode($response);    
}
else
{
$response ["exists"] = FALSE;

echo json_encode($response);
}
}
else{
$response["error_message"] = "Se requiere Email y Contrasena";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

y esta es la función

```
 public function checkExistUser($email,$contrasena)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email=? AND Contrasena=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$contrasena);
    $result=$stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    }else{
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

al ejecutarlo en chrome solo me sale
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /home/.../public_html/phps/db_functions.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /home/u819309222/domains/XYZ/public_html/phps/checkuser.php(13): DB_Functions->checkExistUser('asd', 'asd') #1 {main} thrown in /home/....XYZ.com/public_html/phps/db_functions.php on line 21

siendo esta la linea 21 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$contrasena);

//actualización
Me conecto de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
class DB_Connect{
private $conn;
public function connect()
{
require_once 'config.php';
$this->conn = new mysqli (DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

$this->conn-> set_charset("utf8");
return $this->conn;

}

}
?>
```

y aqui está mi db_funnctions

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

class DB_Functions
{
private $conn;
function __construct()
{
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}
function __destruct()
{
    //TODO:IMPLEMENT METHOD DESTR
}
//cheeck user registrer return true or false
public function checkExistUser($email,$contrasena)
{
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email=? AND 
Contrasena=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$contrasena);
$result=$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
$stmt->close();
return true;
}else{
$stmt->close();
return false;
}
}
```

MUCHAS GRACIAS SU AYUDA

Comment: No te muestra ningún otro mensaje?

Comment: no ningún otro mensaje

Comment: Has dump( _ _ DIR _ _ ) antes del require_once quizás no estés apuntando al directorio en el que esperas encontrar la clase. Puse espacios en los guiones bajos para que se muestren. debes quitarlos.

Comment: modifiqué la configuración php para que muestre errores y me salió esto                                                                                                      Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /home/.../public_html/phpKoob/db_functions.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /home/u819309222/domains/XYZ/public_html/phps/checkuser.php(13): DB_Functions->checkExistUser('asd', 'asd') #1 {main} thrown in /home/....XYZ.com/public_html/phps/db_functions.php on line 21       siendo esta la linea 21         $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$contrasena);

Comment: @quevedo comprobé ya el directorio, ya que hay otras funciones php más simples en la misma ubicación que si se ejecutan normalmente

Comment: Verificaste que conn haya sido construido; está PDO disponible?

Comment: Has comprobado que el mysql en el host se conecte ?... es probable que el bindParam te de error porque no existe en $stmt  y puede ser porque no esta bien el $this->conn .

Comment: Muestra el código de __DB_Functions()__

Comment: Ni siquiera sabemos si estás usando `mysqli` o `PDO`, como dice @Piropeator, muestra el contenido del archivo `db_functions.php`, si están ahí las credenciales de conexión las puedes sustituir por `***`. Eso es lo primero para poder ayudarte: saber qué API estás usando para conectarte.

Comment: @MauricioJavierBiott si comprobe con otras senencias y si conecta

Answer (score 0):

Primero el error indica que no se puede hacer un bindparams porque tu query tiene algo mal y retorna false
Debes hacer un:

```
if(!$stmt){
 print_r($this->conn>error_list);
 die($mysqli->errno . " | "  .$mysqli->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$contrasena);
```

Como puedes ver aqui te lo explican y te dan ejemplos de validacion referencia:
[Mysqli preparada](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Amigo hice eso y lo único que me muestra es la palabra Array ( )__Agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: intenta ahora a ver?

Answer (score 0):

Según indicas, en la **línea 21** tienes el error:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$contrasena);
```

La sintaxis correcta es [bindparam()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
Y como utilizas una sentencia preparada con parámetros de sustitución de signos de interrogación, debes corregir lo anterior y considerar esto:

```
$stmt->bindparam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindparam(2, $contrasena, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Consideré ***PDO::PARAM_STR*** si tus variables **$email** y **$contrasena** son *String*, si son enteros considerar ***PDO::PARAM_INT***
Espero que esto solucione tu problema.